# Apple ID for developer enterprise program

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-developer-program

We need to enroll in Developer Enterprise Program.
The first step is to have a Apple ID, for this reason we are going to create it.

When you are going to create it, the page, ask you first name, last name and birthday.

Should that data be from a member of the development team?

What is the good practice to create the Apple ID?

Comment: I don't know about "good practice", but we have a couple of "general" purpose Apple ID's we use for testing and administration purposes. Generally we've used the companies inception date or, if that produces a to young age, just a random value which suitable for your needs. We also have ID's for each of our developers as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be good if the data you provide is from a member of the development team.